# Webdriver.io browser.elementIdDisplayed(ID) is not returning boolean

Tags: webdriver-io

I'm trying to use webdriver.io function `browser.elementIdDisplayed(element.ELEMENT)`, but it doesn't return a boolean as the docs says. Instead it returns some kind of object.

I'm confused, how can I get a value from this if the element is displayed or not?
Please help.

I have tried also with `browser.elementIdDisplayed(element.ELEMENT).value` but it is always true?

Comment: Why don't you use browser.isVisible(elementsSelector);

Answer (score 0):

It was ok to use
`browser.elementIdDisplayed(element.ELEMENT).value`,
but my other logic of verifying that element was displayed was wrong.